# to cache or not to cache, that is the query

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have a PHP application that heavily relies on mysql's `information_schema` to gather information about table structures, columns types and relations, etc. Specifically `information_schema.columns`, `information_schema.key_column_usage` and `information_schema.tables`.

On each request, several queries to those tables are executed; an average of 10 to 15.

Now, while this actions are not necesarily slowing down the application, Since the schema doesn't change over time (or at least not constantly) I was thinking about implementing some cache system to minimize this type of queries; nothing fancy, maybe storing the result data as json in a text file and then read this file to retrieve the information that I would normally get via SQL.

But before doing that, there's some questions that are running through my mind: it's 2017 and we have massive disk storage, lots of fast RAM and microprocessors that can perform trillions of operations per second...

- Should a cache system must still be implemented?
- Could data selection from `information_schema` decrease
  performance?

At this moment, only a few users access the app and query a few thousand records. But it is expected to reach hundreds of users accessing millions of records.

Comment: If you expect hundreds of thousands of users, then I would guess caching is something you would probably want/need.  I believe the MySQL documentation covers well using tools like Memcache.

Comment: Not sure caching in txt file will be faster. You should try to put some microtimes and make a big ugly loop so you'll see whats faster. `$time_start = microtime_float();

// Do what you want 10000 times

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;`

Comment: I would consider creating a php file containing all these scheme data. Have a separate script to update this php file when needed (run manually when you change the db if you have control of the db, or maybe schedule to run at x interval).
An included php file would get the gain you're looking for if you're using any php opcode caching.

Comment: Without question you need a caching layer for metadata.